# Ghostscript BoundingBox pdfinfo -box vs gs -sDevice=bbox

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, bounding-box

I will to know the difference between BoundingBox information which is out of commands `pdfinfo -box` and `gs -sDevice=bbox`.

`pdfinfo -box`output :

```
  $pdfinfo -box tempCmykPdfFile.pdf
  Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.20
  CreationDate:   Tue Mar  7 09:48:56 2017
  ModDate:        Tue Mar  7 09:48:56 2017
  Tagged:         no
  Pages:          1
  Encrypted:      no
  Page size:      212.6 x 113.39 pts
  MediaBox:           0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
  CropBox:            0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
  BleedBox:           0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
  TrimBox:            0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
  ArtBox:             0.00     0.00   212.60   113.39
  File size:      20886 bytes
  Optimized:      no
  PDF version:    1.5
```

While `gs -sDevice=bbox` output:

```
 $gs -sDevice=bbox tempCmykPdfFile.pdf
 GPL Ghostscript 9.20 (2016-09-26)
 Copyright (C) 2016 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
 Processing pages 1 through 1.
 Page 1
 %%BoundingBox: 13 48 199 100
 %%HiResBoundingBox: 13.986000 48.181006 198.435017 99.220989
```

`BoundingBox` information is different in both the case and I am not to figure out the `why`. Could anyone kindly help me to understand the difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

BoundingBox is the smallest area which encloses all the marks. The various Boxes defined in PDF files (many of which are optional) are not Bounding Boxes.

Without seeing your PDF file I cannot say what box(es) it actually contains, very possibly it only contains a MediaBox, and so that's the size you get.

If there is any white space around the edges of the content, then that is not counted for the BoundingBox, as it only counts marks.

In short, these are different measurements for different purposes.